# Code Ingniter PHP SQL Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables to manage sites, geofences and keys in those sites.

Sites to Geofences is one-to-many.  Sites to Keys is one-to-many.

```
    Sites 
       id       int      PK
       name     varchar
       deleted  bool

    Geofences
       id       int      PK
       site_id  int 
       lat      double
       lon      double
       rad      double

    Keys
       id       int      PK
       site_id  int
       deleted  bool
```

SELECT STATEMENT:

```
    SELECT *, SUM(IF(kc.deleted = 0, 1, 0)) AS 'KeyCount'
    FROM Keys kc 
    INNER JOIN Geofences g ON kc.id = g.site_id
    INNER JOIN Sites s ON s.id = kc.site_id 
    GROUP BY kc.site_id;
```

I want to count the keys in each site where the key and site aren't deleted, as well as get back the geofence data for each site in one MySQL statement.

Sample table data :

```
Sites -----------------------------------

id     name       deleted
1      site_one   0
2      site_two   0
3      site_three 0

Geofences -----------------------------------

id     site_id    lat     lon     rad
1      1          25.5    -123.4  50            
2      1          22.44   -123.3  50
3      1          20.1    -122.5  50
4      2          27.22   -120.5  50
5      2          28.999  -121.11 50
6      3          29.8    -122    75

Keys -----------------------------------

id     site_id    deleted
1      1          0
2      1          1
3      1          0
4      1          0
5      2          0 
5      3          0
```

Any help would be great, i've been trying to figure it out for 2 hours now..

Comment: I take it `deleted`=0 means it's not deleted?

Comment: Hi Ashwin, that's correct :)

Comment: Cool....I was asking for a sample output because I can't understand how to output the count of keys and the geofence information in a single table. If you  could modify your question and add a sample output, it'd probably make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the count of keys per site only considering undeleted sites and keys and the geofence information but the key count and site information (id and name) is obviously (and wastefully) repeated for each geofence.

```
select X.*, g.* from
(
    select s.id as Site_Id, s.name as SiteName, count(kc.id) key_count
    from sites s inner join keys kc on s.Id = kc.site_id
    where s.deleted = 0 and kc.deleted=0
    group by s.Id, S.name
) X inner join GeoFences g on X.Site_Id = g.site_id
```

This is all I could glean from your question. If you require something else, please provide a sample output.

Comment: Thanks Ashwin, i will test it out tomorrow and answer it as correct if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of the Keys.deleted column is 1 or 0 you can use Sum

Try this one:

```
Select g.*,
SUM(k.deleted) AS 'KeyCount'
FROM Sites AS s 
Geofences AS g ON s.id = g.site_id
JOIN  Keys AS k ON s.id = k.site_id
BY g.id;
```

Comment: Thanks John, i will test it out tomorrow and answer it as correct if it works.  Cheers for your help